# How do you make page not scroll to top when clicking a # link?

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have a bunch of divs set up with a class that triggers a jquery click function.

The divs each have just this in them so that the hand cursor appears on mouseover

```
<a href="#">▼</a>
```

Problem is, the page scrolls to the top on click (which makes sense).

What's the way to not have the page jump to the top, while making the hand cursor appear on mouseover?

Thanks guys.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Cheers CBroe - that's worked and made it wayyyy more usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use an anchor tag just set style="cursor:pointer;"

Comment: Cheers dcc. So do I remove the <a href="#"></a> altogether from <div class="expFold"><a href="#">▼</a></div>, or just the #? I tried removing the link altogether, and now the $('#mainDiv').on('click', '.expFold', function (event) doesn't work.

Comment: I would remove the anchor tag all together as it's unncessary markup.  Place the style="cursor:pointer;" on your div tag.. or better yet .expFold { cursor:pointer; } in the CSS to keep your markup clean since you have the class assigned already.  If it's not working without the anchor tag, it's likely an error in your javascript.  If you'd like to post your javascript in your question I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks dcc - I'd forgotten to remove the "a" references from my click function - it was dependent on the anchor. Got rid of them, and it works beaut now! Cheers mate. I'm going to run with your answer, as it'll mean less code throughout my project - I have lot's of divs I can do the same to by stripping out the anchors.

Comment: Well, you are minimizing usability as well – if you just use any arbitrary element with cursor:pointer, that may be fine to click on using the mouse, but it’ll be unusable for users using their keyboard to navigate around a page. (Yes, you could go fix that again using tabindex, but using an `a` element for clickable stuff that’s supposed to trigger a certain action is perfectly fine.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `javascript:void()` instead of `#` as shown below

`<a href="javascript:void()">▼</a>`